# Superio Job Board + WP All Export Pro Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

What is the WordPress action hook that fires when an employee/candidate creates an account? The goal is to export the user information once their account is created.

We are trying to use the WP All Export Pro Plugin → Real-time Export feature so each time a new user signs up, it should trigger an export that includes user information.

The limitation is that the Real-time export is not getting triggered because of compatibility issues with Superio Job Plugin. The support team for WP All Export Pro Plugin was contacted and they provided a php code to use but in order to use that code we need the ACTION HOOK that fires when an employee/candidate creates an account.